# How I will display latest image to ImageView Another Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, android-external-storage

My Application takes a picture from custom camera and save image to external storage.I save image by use code this.

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm", Locale.KOREA);
        Date now = new Date();
        String path = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test"+".jpg");
        String Newpath = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"test_"+formatter.format(now)+".jpg");

        Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo,480,640,false);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70,bytes);

        File f = new File(Newpath);
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
            File file = new File(path);
            file.delete();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

example result > "test_13_12_2019_15_24" , "test_13_12_2019_15_26" , "test_13_12_2019_15_28"

It's time to now in external storage after take a picture but I want it show "test_13_12_2019_15_28" (latest picture) to imageView in another activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can read your file like this.

```
public StringBuilder fromInternal(String filename) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = context.openFileInput(filename);
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new 
            InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb;
    }
```